# file_get_contents not working on the server but working fine on local machine

Tags: php

i have a php script that call a web service to retrieve json data the script is working fine on my local machine but not working on the online server it return empty string

```
$url = "https://magentoorders.elarabygroup.com/Service.asmx/AvailableToPromise";
try {
$contextOptions = array(
   'http'      => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'timeout' => 500,
    'header' => "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                "Content-Type: application/json\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: 0"
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);
var_dump(file_get_contents($url, false, $context));
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if your server allows file_get_contents() to open URL. Check if `allow_url_fopen` is set to true in your php.ini or server configuration.

You can look at [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) to get more help

Information from manual

> allow_url_fopen boolean
>
> This option enables the URL-aware fopen wrappers that enable accessing URL object like files. Default wrappers are provided for the access of remote files using the ftp or http protocol, some extensions like zlib may register additional wrappers.

The other option is to use CURL

Comment: allow_url_fopen = on on the server

Comment: I don't understand. You can set it in many places even in php file with `ini_set()` it all depends on the level of access to the server. As I said if you can't configure server then use CURL instead.

Answer (score 0):

as the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) says:

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen
>   wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to
>   specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for
>   links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have,
>   notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they
>   may provide.

so fopen wrappers are not enabled on host

Comment: fopen: "If the open fails, an error of level E_WARNING is generated. "

Comment: when i did var_dump(fopen($url, 'r', false, $context)) it returns this string "resource(3) of type (stream)"

Comment: i updated my code like this    $file = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
                $response = json_decode(stream_get_contents($file));
                var_dump($response); now it return NULL

Comment: i tried var_dump(fread($file,50)) it return string(0) "" i dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by using this code instead

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);                 
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'');
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,200);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ));
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: so you used CURL as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for some weird reason my old server setting wont add header with this code

```
$header = "Authorization: key=AAAAiQXvgZA:APA91bGKc12FiRd3l3jz\r\n"."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"."User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU iPad OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X; en-us)   AppleWebKit/535.1+ (KHTML like Gecko) Version/7.2.0.0 Safari/6533.18.5\r\n";

        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
              'method'  => 'POST',
              'content' => $data,
              'header' => $header,
              "ssl"=>array(
                              "verify_peer"=>false,
                              "verify_peer_name"=>false
                            )
            )
        );

      $context  = stream_context_create($options);

      $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

I have to walk around by adding the following code before use stream_context_create:

```
ini_set("user_agent" , "Mozilla/3.0\r\nAccept: */*\r\nX-Padding: Foo\r\nAuthorization: key=AAAAiQXvgZA:APA91bGKc12FiRd3l3jzIgMVsF9Dkn25xF\r\nContent-Type: application/json");
```

Hope this help someone someday and sorry for my bad english !