# PHP file_get_contents works on Local but not on server

Tags: php

I used file_get_contents to upload image and I am using `webcam.js` to capture image. it is working on my local but when i move it to my online server it's not working, so i try to search whats going on and lead me to `allow_url_fopen` so i check in my `cpanel` if `allow_url_fopen` is on and i navigate `PHP Selector | options` and prove that it is `on` so I am hoping someone have any idea what is the next move I need to do. to make it work.

**php:**

```
<?php

//set random name for the image, used time() for uniqueness

$filename =  time() . '.jpg';
$filepath = '../images/profile/';

      $patient_id = $_SESSION['patient_current_id'];

      $sql  = "UPDATE patients SET ";
      $sql .= "image_path = '{$filename}' ";
      $sql .= "WHERE id = {$patient_id} ";
      $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
      $image = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

//read the raw POST data and save the file with file_put_contents()
$result = file_put_contents( $filepath.$filename, file_get_contents('php://input') );
if (!$result) {
    print "ERROR: Failed to write data to $filename, check permissions\n";
    exit();
}

echo $filepath.$filename;
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631972/file-get-contents-not-working-on-the-server-but-working-fine-on-local-machine

Comment: Try enabling your PHP warnings/errors. And, what error code you are getting ?

Comment: yes.. i on display_errors but no errors display

Comment: you can check this link http://clinicaaquino.com/sample/ so you can so what happen

Answer (score 0):

- Although the most promising cause could be to verify if `allow_url_fopen` is set to true in your php.ini.
- It that's sets to TRUE, Check if your sever admin has disabled any such functionality ?

Alternatively you can also try using [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) to get the file's content.

Comment: @jhunlio Enable you PHP warnings/errors, To check for exact cause. Also Let us knw what error code your are getting ?

Comment: i know that this issue is old but could you tell if you solve it? because i have to use file_get_contents method because of an third party extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cUrl instead of file_get_contents.

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $data = curl_exec("http://www.example.com");
 curl_close($ch);
 $result = file_put_contents( $filepath.$filename, $data );
```